# Font Awesome unicode "\f046" not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome Unicode (https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/check-square-o) on my webpage.

but it is showing as below.

[image]

I spend a lot of time searching for the reason why Unicode not showing in Chrome on the internet. but still no luck.

```css
.myClass {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.myClass::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f046";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<span class='myClass'>Hiiii</span>
```

Comment: `.fa-check-square-o ` (aks `\f046`) is v. 4, whilst the version you are using appears to be 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in this page, the icon you are search for is `\f14a`

https://fontawesome.com/icons/check-square?style=regular

It says:

`This icon replaces Font Awesome 4's fa-check-square-o`

Note that the link you shared is for Font Awesome 4, but in the HTML you used the version 5.

Answer (score 2):

There is no icon with value `/f046` that you can use as a pseudo-element. Check this cheat sheet for the icons you can use:

https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet