# Why doesn't my checkbox get checked when I click on it, but the linked text turns green?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, checkbox

**Problem**: when I click on the checkbox or the text next to it, the text turns green but the checkbox doesn't get checked.

**Question**: How can I make my checkbox checked when being clicked on it?

I've tried quite a few things to solve this problem, changed the value from 0 to 1, removed and edited at the bottom of the code, literally deleting the scripts at the bottom, change some classes etc. Nothing I've tried seem to work properly.

Here is the entire code since I don't think the problem lies only in the input tag:
**https://jsfiddle.net/yeLnh24x/**

```
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Fix for Firefox autofocus CSS bug
    // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943276/html-5-autofocus-messes-up-css- 
    loading/18945951#18945951
    </script>
    <style>
    body, span.label._label_transparent {
    color: #333;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body class="cover">
    <div class="login-wrap">
    <span class="brand">
    <img src="https://genesis.market/img/logo/genesis.svg" alt="Genesis" style="width: 
    150px;">    </span>
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Sign In</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form id="login-form" class="prevent-doublesubmit" 
    action="https://genesis.market/guest/login" method="post" data-nonce="Ap3NzdOgcxSNuFWp">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf-clientzone" value="e9W5y-pj5UkIbKmvn2- 
    kHP5xoJCd8bJUKgtfBaq2mmiBFz9MZjoZU_KQbNBG96VtnPCJHEYt7dxiCD4ZkajvoA==">    <div 
    class="form-group field-loginform-login required">

    <input type="text" id="loginform-login" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[login]" 
    placeholder="Login" autofocus aria-required="true">

    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
    </div>    <input type="hidden" id="loginform-password-hash" name="LoginForm[password]" 
    value="">    <div class="form-group field-loginform-password required">

    <input type="password" id="loginform-password" class="form-control" value="" 
    placeholder="Password" aria-required="true">

    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
    </div>    <div class="form-group field-loginform-rememberme">
    
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="loginform-rememberme">



    <input type="checkbox" id="loginform-rememberme" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" value="0" 
    checked>
    Remember me for 2 weeks
    </label>
    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>

    </div>
    </div>    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ready-enable" disabled data- 
    loading-text="Logging in...">Login</button>    <br>
    <br>

    Don't have an account yet? <a href="/register.html">Sign Up!</a></form>        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/essentials.min.js?v=1619261302"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/assets/afe82d8/yii.js?v=1617716624"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/assets/afe82d8/yii.validation.js?v=1617716624"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/assets/afe82d8/yii.activeForm.js?v=1617716624"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/ark/ark.core.min.js?v=1619261301"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/ark/ark.core-afterwards.min.js?v=1619261301"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/login.min.js?v=1619261302"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/app/app.core.min.js?v=1619261301"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/app/app.login.min.js?v=1619261301"></script>
    <script src="https://genesis.market/js/app/app.core-afterwards.min.js?v=1619261301"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#login-form').yiiActiveForm([{"id":"loginform- 
    login","name":"login","container":".field-loginform-login","input":"#loginform- 
    login","error":".help-block.help-block-error","validate":function (attribute, value, 
    messages, deferred, $form) {value = yii.validation.trim($form, attribute, 
    []);yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Login cannot be 
    blank."});yii.validation.regularExpression(value, messages, {"pattern":/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0- 
    9_]*$/,"not":false,"message":"Login is invalid.","skipOnEmpty":1});}},{"id":"loginform- 
    password","name":"password","container":".field-loginform-password","input":"#loginform- 
    password","error":".help-block.help-block-error","validate":function (attribute, value, 
    messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Password 
    cannot be blank."});}},{"id":"loginform- 
    rememberme","name":"rememberMe","container":".field-loginform- 
    rememberme","input":"#loginform-rememberme","error":".help-block.help-block-e 
    rror","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) 
    {yii.validation.boolean(value, messages, 
    {"trueValue":"1","falseValue":"0","message":"Remember me must be either \"1\" or 
    \"0\".","skipOnEmpty":1});}}], []);
    });</script></body>


     


If someone can take a look at it, and maybe provide help, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Cut your code down to "minimal"! Creating a [repro] is also the first step in debugging yourself. Note that SO is run by volunteers. They spend their free time to help others and it would be excessive to ask them to read through dozens of libraries.

Comment: Can you cut down the code to be more compact? Are all those css required?

Comment: I searched for the flaws in the compact code, but I really couldn't find it, I really think it's necessary to have all the code, but all right I'll edit it.

Comment: pretty easy. Remove one CSS file (the bottom one first) and check if the issue still is present. Keep doing that until you find the CSS files and JS files that cause the issue.

Comment: I've tried that, but no successful attempts unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox actually changes when clicking on it, but the box that the checkbox displays was actually a missing glyph.

The checked box's unicode is \f046, which there is a similar question before.

[Font Awesome unicode "\f046" not showing in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404181/font-awesome-unicode-f046-not-showing-in-chrome)

[checkbox unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjInX.png)

So it may be an issue in your imported css code, just find it and fix it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really can't find it though, I've tried so many stuff.